# How can I load a Angular controller "manually" cause routing is managed by a different engine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

The main engine/routing (I'm trying to replace step by step) is not written with Angular.

Since I'm using Angular for some pages I have an issue when I try to land any page written with Angular, using a function, written with a different engine, that renders different view eg: *header, main, footer*.

In the index file I've put angularApp script-link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/ang/myApp.js"></script>
```

and a main Controller:

```
<div id="view-container" ng-controller="myAppController as appCtrl"></div>
```

Inside that I've put views with they own Angular controller:

```
<div class="row bar hidden" ng-controller="StatusBarController as sbarCtrl">
```

All the controller (and js files of the views) are loaded inside the page dynamically by the engine by this function:

```
function attachJavaScriptFileInitial(fileURL) {
    if(minifiedJS) fileURL = fileURL.replace(".js", ".min.js");
    if(cachingOnOff) fileURL = fileURL+"?v="+appVersion;

    var jsPath =  fileURL.match(/^templates\/.+/) ? fileURL : "javascripts/"+ minifiedDir + fileURL;
    return $.cachedScript(jsPath);
}
```

On controller:

```
var ajaxCallsBar = {
    "getPerson"          : {"URL" : "user/adult/"},
    "getCard"           : {"URL" : "mny/card/"+viewingAsId},
};



console.log(angular);//works
console.log(myApp);//works

myApp.controller("StatusBarController", ["$scope","initAjaxCalls", "dataAggregator", function($scope, initAjaxCalls, dataAggregator){
    console.log("INSIDE: StatusBarController");
    var self = this;

    initAjaxCalls(ajaxCallsBar).then(function(data){
        dataAggregator(data, $scope);
        self.fName = $scope.getPerson.firstName;
    });
```

The main problem is that if I don't refresh the page, the controllers don't work at all, as they didn't exist.

- index : `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/ang/myApp.js"></script>`
- pageA-block1: controller1
- pageA-block2: controller2
- pageA-block3: controller3

All these blocks are loaded inside a main  (block container) with myApp("myAppController")

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is. You say you're already loading the files.

Comment: The main problem is that the controllers don't work at all, as they didn't exist.

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: What should I put in?

Comment: Are you injected your `ngApp` directive anywhere?

Comment: I added some additional infoes